# How should I solve/approach the cracks in my garage's cinderblock walls?

Tags: repair, garage, foundation, masonry, cinderblock

I just bought a property with a detached garage and it looks to have cracks in the walls. It has no drainage on the roof, which is probably causing settling issues. I plan to add gutters to the garage, but what should I do about the cracks?

I'm noticing that some cracks follow the edge of the blocks, while some cracks go through the middle of the bricks.

Is this something that I can patch myself? How concerned should I be here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Patch the cracks with an exterior grade caulk. If you've got clay soil, then there could be crack growth and new cracks in the future.

The stair pattern cracking is typical to settlement. Your left image's cracking starts narrow down low and grows wide up high, where that's another settlement pattern. Settlement, then, explains your cracks.

For clay soils, settlement can take a long time (up to 50 years and beyond). Some clay soils are expansive and/or frost heave susceptible, where seasonal moisture and/or seasonal freezing can lift things to cause cracks that could be confused with settlement cracks. Building code foundation depth requirements are calibrated to mitigate this risk, though, so a by-the-book foundation shouldn't have this problem above ground. If your area has lots of clay soil, then there could be crack growth and new cracks in your future (from long time-horizon settlement, but probably not expansion or frost heave).

For granular soils, settlement takes 6 months and that's it, no more movement. It could take time for the resultant cracks to appear, but the time horizon is still small. There's an exception for granular soils with significant organics, where the organics can render the soil expansive and frost heave susceptible (above the frost line, of course), but in most areas you scrape off the top layer of organic contaminated soil to get down to a mineral layer at a shallow depth (building codes prescribe removing the organics, but if you're building in a swamp, then I imagine that there's not much that you can do to avoid organics).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer, settling of soil can use this sort of cracking, but not normally through a brick/block.

I would get plans from the local authority (or the previous owner).  If there is no reinforcing bars both vertically and horizontally then you should be worried.

You can buy cavity sensors that can detect metal inside a block wall.  I have one, and its amazing, it detects copper pipes and rebars etc.  Maybe you can rent one for you local hire place.